# Jgrasp C++ compile issues

Tags: c++, jgrasp

When I try to compile a simple source code in c++ using jgrasp i get this

> ----jGRASP wedge2 error: command "g++" not found.  ----   This
>   command must be in the current working directory  ----   or on the
>   current PATH to use this function.  ----   PATH is ";C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\".  ----jGRASP: operation complete.

anyone know how to fix it?
Im using windows 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either don't have a C++ compiler installed on your machine or you have a C++ compiler installed and have not added it to your PATH.

Comment: @wat Go to 'Settings' -> 'PATH/CLASSPATH' -> 'Workspace', then click the 'new' button off to the right under the PATH tab. Find your compiler on your machine and click 'Ok'

Comment: I found it but I have no idea where to fine my compiler I have visual studio ultimate 2012 so I should have many available.

Comment: If you have visual studio ultimate 2012 why are you using jGrasp?

Comment: Well Im using it for simplistic console programing with minimal accessibility from the UI.. In other words learning. I installed another one and got it working thanks.